# error 401 me impide hacer un login

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jsonwebtoken

Estoy probando iniciar sesión en la pagina que creé. Sera algo en el react-redux, porque puedo iniciar sesión usando Postman.

```
import {createSlice} from "@reduxjs/toolkit"

const userSlice = createSlice({
   name:"user",
    initialState:{
        currentUser : null,
        isFetching: false,
        error: false
    },
    reducers:{
        loginStart:(state) => {
            state.isFetching = true
        }, 
        loginSuccess:(state, action) => {
            state.isFetching = false;
            state.currentUser = action.payload;
        },
        loginFailure:(state) => {
            state.isFetching = false
            state.error = true
        },
    },
});

 export const {loginStart, loginSuccess, loginFailure} = userSlice.actions
 export default userSlice.reducer;
```

```
import { loginFailure, loginStart, loginSuccess } from "./userRedux"
import { publicRequest } from "../requestMethod"

export const login = async (dispatch, user) => {
    dispatch(loginStart());
    try {
        const res = await publicRequest.post("http://localhost:8085/auth/login", user)
        dispatch(loginSuccess(res.data))
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch(loginFailure())
    }
}
```

(editado, me olvide de ponerlo antes) Y esta es la parte de Login.js

```
const Login = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const { isFetching, error } = useSelector((state) => state.user)

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    login(dispatch,{username, password})
  }
 
...
                <Input 
                  placeholder='username'
                  onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}/>
                <Input 
                  placeholder='password'
                  type="password"
                  onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
                <Button onClick={handleClick} 
                  disabled=isFetching}>Bienvenido de Vuelta</Button>
                {error && <Error>Algo salio mal</Error>}
  )
}
```

(editado... otra vez) agrego la parte backend del login. Tal vez sea algo con el jsonwebtoken

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que tiene que pasar el que salga loginSuccess al iniciar sesión, pero me salta loginFailure

¿Cuál es el problema?

Si tengo que agregar mas info a la pregunta, avisen. Desde ya, muchas gracias

Comment: Supongo que necesitariamos ver el código de la ruta `/auth/login` para empezar

Comment: O un ejemplo de una request exitosa en Postman por ejemplo

Comment: Cierto, no me di cuenta que no lo agregue. Ya lo incluyo

Comment: En VSCode me sale el error "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client". Recién ahora me doy cuenta

Comment: Me refería al código del servidor que maneja la ruta /auth/login

Comment: O sea, la parte backend del código... ? (perdon por no escribir hace rato, me agarro el covid) Estoy usando JWT, tal vez sea eso

Comment: El problema es que el front está mandando el nombre de usuario como `username` pero el backend espera recibirlo como `nombre`. Lo más sencillo sería cambiarlo en el backend. En vez de `req.body.nombre` pon `req.body.username`

Comment: ok, pero tendre que cambiar tambien el schema de mongoose

Comment: desde el schema, tenia nombre, email, password y otros. Me lo hice mas facil y cambie a email, y ya me funciona. Gracias!